# createElement error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, createelement

I am getting the follow error on the following line in IE8 ( not in IE9 or chrome or firefox )

```
popup = document.createElement('div');
```

Error :

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Fri, 5 Aug 2011 13:39:41 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 72
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.7.1/fquick/script.js
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: is this code inside an iframe or another window?

Comment: you may have call the document.createElement function before the document tree is loaded. try placing the script on window onload function

Comment: The origin from that error is not the line you mentioned. Even if MSIE is behind of some things, it certainly knows about `document.createElement()`

Comment: @jerjer - its fixed, strange..thanx anyway..answer is below

Comment: try checking also if the document ==> was not overwritten with another variable. try searching for "document="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the line to

```
var popup = document.createElement('div');
```

and it works. funny.