# document.createElement is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, createelement

The document.createElement('a') tag is not working in IE8 in this snippet of code.  It works fine in chrome and firefox.  When I check through IE, it seems as if its the first line of code that's broken.

```
        item = document.createElement('a');
        item.setAttribute('id', 'memorize');
        item.innerHTML = "<?php echo wzfactory::get_xml('menu_item', 4, $com); ?>";
        item.setAttribute('class', 'menu_button');
        item.onclick = function() {redirect('memorizor', 'memorize', 0);};
        menu_div.appendChild(item);
```

Does anybody know why this is the case, and if there is a crappy browser workaround?  I haven't been able to find the workaround.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please *always* quote the exact error message you are getting. Also, seeing as it's a JS question, it would be better if you showed the final generated HTML/JS instead of the PHP source

Comment: How have you determined that `createElement` isn't working?

Comment: Broken how? What errors do you get? What debugging tools are you using? What makes you think the problem is with the first line of code? Why are you showing us PHP that generates JavaScript instead of the JavaScript itself? Why are you using `setAttribute` which is known to be broken in many versions of IE (especially for setting class)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [createElement error in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957249/createelement-error-in-ie8)

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things that might "break" the functionality.. try this instead:

```
item = document.createElement('a');
item.id = 'memorize';
item.href = "#";
item.innerHTML = "<?php echo wzfactory::get_xml('menu_item', 4, $com); ?>";
item.className 'menu_button';
item.onclick = function() {
    redirect('memorizor', 'memorize', 0);
    return false;
};
menu_div.appendChild(item);
```

First, assign the `id` directly and not via `setAttribute` and second, anchor without `href` becomes mere text, not link so you must assign that attribute.