# document.head.appendChild(element) ie ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, appendchild

i am having an issue appending a script to the head in ie7/8

this is the code i am using

```
var requireTag = document.createElement('script');
requireTag.setAttribute('type',         'text/javascript');
requireTag.setAttribute('src',          link+ 'require.js');
requireTag.setAttribute('data-main',    link+ 'data');

document.head.appendChild(requireTag);
```

this is the error i get

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property
'appendChild': object is null or undefined
```

I found this [createElement error in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957249/createelement-error-in-ie8) and tried updating my code to have

```
var appendChild = document.head.appendChild(requireTag);
```

but still get the same error. Can anyone help?

Comment: The *head* property of the *document* object was introduced in HTML5, so any browser that isn't fully HTML5 compliant may not support it. The HTML5 specification is a "living" document, so there is no way to specify when it was introduced (i.e. in what version), which makes it difficult to determine which browsers may not support it other than by trial and error.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , `document.head` isn't available to IE<9. Just use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(requireTag);
```

Comment: MDN is not a definitive reference for Microsoft applications, better to reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which says the same thing, but is a more authoritative source).

Answer (score 15):

I believe `document.head` isn't supported in those browsers.

Try this instead:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(requireTag);
```